# Is haber used in plural conjugation only when it is being used as an auxiliary verb, such as in a perfect tense?

Tags: haber

Since it is incorrect to use the plural of haber when the object is plural, does it mean that the only time we conjugate haber in plural is when it is being used as an auxiliary verb?

For example:
Habra rumores

Habran dicho rumores

Comment: Also when haber is used to mean tener.

Comment: "Since it is incorrect to use the plural of haber when the object is plural"??

Comment: Lambie, would it help if I say that it is grammatically incorrect to say "habran rumores"? Instead, it should be "habra rumores." I am trying to understand when do we use habran, habremos, etc. in a grammatically correct way.

Comment: Please,refer to "¿Qué forma verbal es la correcta: habrá payasos o habrán payasos?" conversation.

Comment: Dear user0721090601, what do you mean? We don't use "tener" as an auxiliary verb in Spanish. Rather, we use "haber." An I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

*Haber* has three main meanings:

1. As an auxiliary for compound tenses.
2. As a full verb meaning the same as *tener* (archaic), including the phrase *haber de* (which means either "have to" or "must" in the sense of supposing or guessing, and sometimes moral obligation).
3. As an impersonal "existence" verb, and in the phrase *haber que* (meaning "must" only in the sense of obligation).

For (3), the impersonal usage, the verb is only conjugated in the third person singular. This is the same thing that happens with all impersonal verbs in Spanish. (Some verbs are inherently impersonal, like *llover*; others can be made impersonal with *se*. And then there's *haber* in a class of its own.)

For the other two usages, *haber* is conjugated normally. Note that for (1) and (2) the 3rd person present of *haber* is *ha*, but in (3) it's *hay*.

**Examples (upon request):**

1. *Haber* as auxiliary: *"Usted me **ha** insultado." "El maestro **ha** pedido silencio." "**Ha** caído nieve." "Ayer han circulado rumores." "¿He dicho algo malo?" "Supongo que habrá cometido un error."*
2. *Haber* as full verb, with *de*, expressing either guess or moral obligation: *"El señor **ha** de saber que lo están engañando." "He de decir que no me gusta."* There really are not many examples that I can think of, unless you want me to dig up medieval texts.
3. *Haber* as impersonal existence verb: *"**Hay** muchas telarañas en esta habitación." "¿Habrá buenos restaurantes en la isla?" "No **hay** razón para enojarse." "No **hay** motivos para enojarse."* With *que*, expressing impersonal obligation: *"**Hay** que ordenar esta casa." "¿A qué hora **hay** que salir para el aeropuerto?" "Cuando llegamos hubo que abrir las ventanas."*

Comment: Thank you Pablodf76. Can you please give specific examples?  of the use of haber in the plural...hubieron, not as an auxiliary verb, but rather as "there are," if there is such a case.

Comment: As I said, in meaning 3 (*haber* as existence verb) there's no plural verb, ever, precisely because it's impersonal. So for "There were problems" you say *"Hubo problemas"*, with *hubo* (**singular** 3rd person preterite). Using the plural *hubieron* in this case is a common mistake.